# Should I use sub-addresses more?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, sub-address

With regards to privacy, security and performance, is it best practice to use a different sub-address for each different type of activity?

For example, to use one sub-address for exchange use, one for a mining pool, one for donations etc. Or is using them less better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If wallet addresses are like bank account numbers, then subaddresses are like having lots of different bank account numbers for the same bank account.

This means that if you want Alice and Bob to pay you, you can give out a different bank account number to each of them. They then can't confer to figure out they're dealing with the same person.

This also means that if you transact with Alice on multiple occasions, you can give her a different bank account number each time, and she won't be able to know you're a repeat customer.

It's up to you to decide whether this level of privacy is useful to you or not. There is no penalty for using subaddresses. Use them as much or as little as you want.